# Vulnerability Assessment against application

Tags: security

Is it legal to run a vuln assessment vs. a site other than one you currently own?

Say you own a security software and want to test potential clients' websites for vulnerabilities (without their consent) ?

Comment: This isn't a forum for legal advice (and, indeed, you're not going to find one that is, either). What you're describing may well be a violation of the law in many jurisdictions. Legality aside, I wouldn't ever work with a security consultant who came to me with a "pro-bono security assessment". I'd call the cops. There has been a lot of philosophical banter about this kind of thing on the 'net ("xxx hacker finds yyy vulnerability in big-company-name website..." with various conclusions like "...gets a job." or "...gets prosecuted." That's not something I'd gamble with, personally.)

Comment: Is it legal to break the law...? Um... I'm going to have to ask my lawyer about that one. You should do the same.

Answer (score 1):

First off: I am not a lawyer, I'm not offering legal advice and in no way should you interpret my response as establishing an attorney-client relationship. I would recommend you speak with your lawyer before taking any such risks.

That out of the way, the short is answer is maybe. If you're breaking any laws during your assessment, it's illegal. Something as simple as a port scan cout get you in trouble,even if it doesn't cause a denial of service. Something like exploiting a vulnerability, and using it to pivot to their internal network, even more so.

What I'm guessing you're asking, is whether or not them being a potential client, or you just 'trying to help', protects you in anyway from a legal standpoint. It does not. The only way to legally protect your self would be to have a legal contract stating such.

To reiterate. Not a lawyer, talk with one well versed in this type of thing though.

Comment: Beware-- giving legal advice after saying "I'm not a lawyer" is not a "get out of practicing law w/o a license prosecution free" card.

Comment: Thanks, You're probably right, I should explicitly state that.

Comment: You'd probably be better off not answering this ridiculous question at all.

Comment: Perhaps, but I'd prefer to help while protecting myself as best I can. Hopefully keeping someone from making a poor choice in the process.

Comment: Depending on how sensitive the skin of the target is, you could end in deep dodo for "just" portscanning.

Comment: An even better point, and I'm not sure even the lawyers have a grasp on that one :-)